# How to redirect PUT request to POST request in express router route handler?

Tags: express, npm

I am handling PUT /api/checkout route with express router:
   `this.router.put('/:id/checkout', (req, response, next) => { /*...*/ });`

Now as I am handling different types of payments with different third party services one of which expects POST request I am looking for a way handle the PUT request by executing the POST request to third party service endpoint. How do I do that ?

What i did at this point is execute POST request directly with `request.post`.

The challenge at this point is how to handle the resource moved response.

```
request.post({
  url  : 'https://paymentgateway.com/charge',
  form : {
    product_id        : product_id,
    amount            : amount
  }
}, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
```

The response I get here is `httpResponse.statucCode === 302` and `body === <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>`. Not sure how to handle this. HTML form with same request parameters automatically redirects the client to redirect URL.

Comment: If a client is making a `PUT` request to your server, you can't make it do a `POST` request to another server instead (at least not "automatically" by means of an HTTP response code like 30X). Proxying the request like you're doing already is a viable solution.

Comment: The challenge I am facing now is that proxied request returns redirection status code 302. Not sure how to handle it.

Comment: `request` will not follow redirects issued for non-GET requests, unless you set the `followAllRedirects` to `true`.

Answer (score -1):

Returning the `httpResponse` to the client requesting the checkout action does the job. Client handles redirection automatically.

```
}, (err, httpResponse, body) => {

  if (err) {
    logger.error(err);
    return response.status(err.code || 500).send(err);
  }

  return response.status(httpResponse.statusCode).send(httpResponse);
});
```